# Pause Android application when debugging with jdb so catchpoint can be set

Tags: java, android, adb, jdb

Using the developer tools on an emulator I have an application wait for the debugger before starting, but immediately after jdb is attached the application will have an undesirable yet handled exception. I can't debug this exception since jdb wont stop on it. I therefore need to be able to set `catch java.lang.Exception` before the application continues. How can I do that?

I use jdb with:

```
adb forward tcp:7777 jdwp:$(adb jdwp | tail -1); jdb -sourcepath ./wallet/src -attach localhost:7777
```

Answer (score -1):

You can pipe the suspend command into jdb without piping a EOF like so:

```
adb forward tcp:7777 jdwp:$(adb jdwp | tail -1); { echo "suspend"; cat; } | jdb -sourcepath ./wallet/src -attach localhost:7777
```